# How to get the image in center of view using PageControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uipagecontrol

I have 15 images in pagecontrol and I have 15 buttons in my application

Now if I press button 5 at that time image 5 from the page control should be in center of the screen.

if I press button 10 at that time image 10 from the page control should be in center of the screen.

How can I develop this kind of structure in my app?

share your ideas.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this (assuming you're using a scrollview with paging enabled):

```
-(IBAction)goToPage5:(id)sender{
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 5;
    //OR if you have set the tags to your buttons:
    //UIButton *b=(UIButton*)sender;
    //frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * b.tag;
    self.pageControl.currentPage=5;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Assign same tags to your buttons & corresponding images.
>
> Get the button tag on button action.
>
> Get the corresponding image from view using the button tag (both tags
>   will same)
>
> Get the image position in mainView
>
> Scroll/visible the same frame of page-control to the center of your
>   main view

Answer (score 0):

Assign tags for each button and initialize an imageview

```
-(IBAction)YourButtonName:(UIButton *)sender
{
  imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:UIImage imageNamed:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"image%d",sender.tag];
  imageview.center=self.view.center;
}
```